# Change F3 Control in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

In Minecraft, pressing F3 (many devices require you to hold fn in addition) brings up various statistics. I went to the controls and tried to change this menu to a more convenient button, but could not find the control I needed to change. Where can I find this control, and is it possible to change it? Please keep in mind that I understand little about the game; I am asking on a relative's behalf.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Clicking this](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Controls) will lead you to the Minecraft wiki that is relevant to this question.

Based on the information at hand, it seems that you cannot change the function of the F3 key. It is one of the non-configurable controls in the game.

Answer (score 0):

If you will go to the extent of modding the game to see coordinates you can download a mod called *Batty's Coordinates PLUS!* mod.(linked here:https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/batty-ui)

you will also need to install the latest forge api and move the coordinate mod into the mods folder. There are plenty YouTube videos that show how to put a mod into the folder and install the Forge client.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question directly, maybe make it a bit more direct?

Comment: @Penguin To be fair, this question is 4+ years old, and already has an accepted answer. Then again, you make a great point!